# C# - Download file from data URL

Tags: c#

##### Summary

I'm wondering if there is a way to download the content of a [data URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URLs) in C#, more specifically an image.

##### Background

Currently developing a Blazor Hybrid application which saves images from a canvas HTML element. The `toDataUrl()` method is invoked in JavaScript, then the url is retrieved by Blazor using JS interop. I've been having problems using this url to get the image, as `HttpClient` doesn't recognize it's format.

##### What I've tried

###### Using HttpClient

Throws `Java.Net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol`

```cs
var imageUrl = await this.runtime.InvokeAsync<string>(SAVE);
byte[] image;

using HttpClient client = new()

image = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(imageUrl);
```

###### Downloading via JavaScript

Works on Windows, but not Android which is what I'm targeting. I've ensured that the proper permissions were requested.

```js
const anchor = document.createElement('a')
const url = canvas.toDataURL()

anchor.download = 'painting.png'
anchor.href = url

anchor.click()
anchor.remove()
```

Comment: A data url is part of another document. Therefore you must download the main document and parse out the data you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the data url as a string,

First, extract the data [using regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match?view=net-6.0).

Then [convert the base64 to bin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.frombase64string?view=net-6.0) and [save the file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writeallbytes?view=net-6.0).

```
//Input data url
string dataURL;

//Get Path and Filename
string filename = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "image.png");

//Match Regex
var base64Data = Regex.Match(stringName, @"data:image/(?<type>.+?),(?<data>.+)").Groups["data"].Value;
var binData = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Data);

//Write file. This will overwrite any existing file.
File.WriteAllBytes(filename, binData);
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea of downloading a whole file directly through a Blazor component makes me uncomfortable.  Rather than using SignalR to transfer the file using interop, I prefer to make an old-style MVC controller, and submit the file as form data direct from js.  From the controller's point of view, you are basically doing a file upload.

The nice thing about this method is you can send an image file from anywhere you want.

**in Program.cs**

```
// First in services builder:
builder.Services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);
// Then, near end after app.UseRouting():
app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
```

The following is a working code sample for uploading a converted .mp3 file.  I don't have the time to test a working model for your particular data, so you can't copy and paste, but the point is that you send the data as a file.

**Uploader.js**

```
async function UploadAudio(TextClipID, AudioID) {
    let filename = AudioID + ".mp3";
    let fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("file", mp3Blob[TextClipID], filename);
    var postresponse = await fetch('api/SaveAudio/Save/', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: fd
    });

    if (postresponse.ok) {
        // Do happy stuff, like calling a .NET method with the new path for your <img> source.
    }

    else return false;
}
```

Then add a new `Controllers` folder in your project for this and other MVC controllers you might want to use.  Obviously, since mine is serving as an audio upload controller, you'd want to make / find a controller that handles image uploads:

**/Controllers/SaveAudio.cs**

```
public class SaveAudio : Controller
    {
        IWebHostEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

        public SaveAudio(IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
        {
            _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;

        }

        [Route("api/[controller]/Save")]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Save(IFormFile file)
        {
            if (file.ContentType != "audio/mp3")
            {
                return BadRequest("Wrong file type");
            }
            var uploads = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "files", "audio", "Reading");

            var filePath = Path.Combine(uploads, file.FileName );
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                try
                {
                    await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                    return Ok("File uploaded successfully at: " + filePath);
                }
                catch
                {
                    return BadRequest("Wrong file type");
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
```