# httpClient.GetStreamAsync System.NotSupportedException: The 'data' scheme is not supported

Tags: blazor, httpclient, html2canvas

I am trying to save on server an image that is captured with Html2Canvas on Client.

The url of the image is retrieved in javascript code from

```
html2Canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

and is sent to the server where I try to get the stream with

```
await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(imgUrl);
```

But I am getting the following error

System.NotSupportedException: The 'data' scheme is not supported.

The url has the following format

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAByA..
```

Any idea about this?

Comment: `HttpClient`, as the name suggests, is designed for `http` and `https` schemes. You'll probably need to handle the `data` scheme yourself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# - Download file from data URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73087103/c-sharp-download-file-from-data-url)

Comment: HttpClient is used to send requests and receive responses from servers. A [Data URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URLs)  is a URL that contains all its data as an encoded string. That encoding is specified in the URL itself, in this case `base64`. You can use `Convert.FromBaseString` to convert the BASE64 data into bytes.

Comment: Panagioti this is the answer with Convert.FromBaseString, A data url contains all the data of the image, it is not a url. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I thought that html2Canvas.toDataURL() exports a url but it exports data that have to be parsed locally without httpClient